# Spark Datasets groupByKey doesn't work (Java)

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I try to use Dataset's groupByKey method. I can't figure out the problem and **can't find** any working example which **uses groupByKey**.

So let me point out the points, I am looking for in the solution:

1. I want to use groupByKey - there are a lot of example using groupBy("key").agg(function), I know it but don't want to use them (education purposes)
2. I want to use Java - many examples use Scala, again don't want it.
3. The function should preferably be written as lambda expression.

Here is what I did:

```
//Inner class
public static class Bean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String k;
    private int something;

    public Bean(String name, int value) {
        k = name;
        something = value;
    }

    public String getK() {return k;}
    public int getSomething() {return something;}

    public void setK(String k) {this.k = k;}
    public void setSomething(int something) {this.something = something;}
}

//usage
List<Bean> debugData = new ArrayList<Bean>();
debugData.add(new Bean("Arnold", 18));
debugData.add(new Bean("Bob", 7));
debugData.add(new Bean("Bob", 13));
debugData.add(new Bean("Bob", 15));
debugData.add(new Bean("Alice", 27));
Dataset<Row> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(debugData, Bean.class);
df.groupByKey(row -> {new Bean(row.getString(0), row.getInt(1));}, Encoders.bean(Bean.class)); //doesn't compile
```

The error I am getting:

1. Ambiguous method call - The IDE shows warning about both Function1 and MapFunction are matching.
2. The getString and getInt cannot be resolved
3. I can't show/print the result

Comment: @LukasBradley yeah Spark 2.1.0 with Java 8 and scala 2.11.8

Comment: I think you'll need to define your lambda as a MapFunction instead of a Java lambda.  https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/MapFunction.html

Comment: Either drop {} or add missing return to lambda.

Comment: df.groupByKey(row -> (MapFunction) new MapFunction<Row,Bean>(){
        public Bean call(Row row1) { return new Bean(row1.getString(0), row1.getInt(1));}}, Encoders.bean(Bean.class));
Getting ambigious method call though...

Comment: @LukasBradley is it really a lambda? you define the function inline, also there is this ambigious error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Java 8 lambda

```
df.groupByKey(row -> {
            return new Bean(row.getString(0), row.getInt(1));
        }, Encoders.bean(Bean.class));
```

Using `MapFunction`

```
df.groupByKey(new MapFunction<Row, Bean>() {
            @Override
            public Bean call(Row row) throws Exception {
                return new Bean(row.getString(0), row.getInt(1));
            }
        }, Encoders.bean(Bean.class));
```

Comment: I am getting two errors using the lambda sample: 1. ambigious call of the lambda (Function1 or MapPartition) and 2. the get methods of the row are not recognized. Did you try to run this code?

Comment: a different but maybe related question is why the results is Row->Bean shouldn't it be Column->Bean?

Comment: If you want use a particular column from row of Dataset then you can use it. So if you want use "name" column then use return new Bean(row.getString(0));. You might need to add constructor for "name" in your Bean class.

Comment: I am sorry but I am unable to verify this solution works, can you show me how to show/print the result dataset?

Comment: You can use df.groupByKey(row -> {
   return new Bean(row.getString(0));
  }, Encoders.bean(Bean.class)).count().show(); OR df.groupByKey(row -> {
   return row.getString(0);
  }, Encoders.STRING()).count().show();

Comment: The first solution is wrong, but the second is true.

Answer (score 0):

This error arises because `groupByKey` has two overloded implementations. one of these methods gives `MapFunction` as first argument and the second gives `Function1`. Your lambda code can cast to both of them. So you should explicitly declare which one is your intention. Casting is an easy solution:

```
df.groupByKey(row -> (MapFunction<Row, Bean>) new Bean(row.getString(0), row.getInt(1))
    , Encoders.bean(Bean.class));
```